# Progrma says that hash is different but its not

Tags: c

I have a program that generate a hash key from a file and shows that hash. Im trying to check if the result hash key corresponds to the expected hash key. But this is not working, because when the hash key is the same of the expected I gett the message saying "hash is different". Do you see what is not correct?

Some variables related to the question.

```
    BYTE rgbFile[BUFSIZE];
    DWORD cbRead = 0;
    BYTE rgbHash[MD5LEN];
    DWORD cbHash = 0;
    CHAR rgbDigits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
    PCSTR filename = "c:\\Users\\jax\\Desktop\\files\\test.txt";
    CHAR hashExpected[] = "4ab5d20e55ef73e4f412d73c2a201e";
```

In the code below is where it shows a message like "Hash of file is "4ab5d20e55ef73e4f412d73c2a201e" and where I have the comparison:

```
        DWORD i;
        CHAR hashResult= "";
        printf("Hash of file %s is: ", filename);
        for (i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
        {
            printf("%c%c",
                   rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
                   rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
            hashResult = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
            hashResult += rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];

        }

        printf("\n");    
        printf(hashResult);
        if(hashResult == hashExpected){
            printf("hash is the same");
        }
        else{
            printf("hash is different");
        }
```

Update: Also I get always the message "Incorrect":

```
        DWORD i;
        CHAR hashResult[] = {};
        printf("Hash of file %s is: ", filename);
        for (i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
        {
            printf("%c%c",
                   rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4],
                   rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf]);
            hashResult[i] = rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] >> 4];
            hashResult[i] += rgbDigits[rgbHash[i] & 0xf];


        }
        if(hashResult == hashExpected){
            printf("Hash is the same");
        }
        else{
            printf("Hash is different");
        }
```

updated:

```
BOOL test( char array1[] , char array2[] )
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; array1[i] && array2[i]; ++i )
    {
        if( array1[i] != array2[i] )
        {
            return( FALSE );
        }
    }
    return( TRUE );
}
```

Comment: The code you show shouldn't compile without warnings. You have both `CHAR a[] = "…";` and `CHAR b = "";`.  You can't compare strings for equality with `==` but you do.

Comment: Think about how you would compare two arrays: element by element. Two arrays are equal in value only if _all_ the corresponding elements are equal. You can't just make one comparison and then immediately know `"hash is the same"`, you'd have to wait until you know _all_ are the same. If you find that one element doesn't match, then you do immediately know that they are _not_ equal.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. For what I understood with your help the code I update now should work because if it finds two letters different it return false, and if are all icual it returns true. But Im getting always the message "hash is different" and they are icual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some significant issues with types, at least in the comparison

```
if(hashResult == hashExpected){
```

`hashResult` is a `CHAR` and `hashExpected` (with no array index) is the address in memory where an array of `CHAR` begins.  You need to compare the actual values stored in that array, not just an address of where it is.

*Edit: I noticed `hashResult` is a `CHAR`, and not an array, as previously written.  Either way, the `hashResult == hashExpected` comparison is inappropriate.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For what I understand the issue was that hashResult was storing with no array index. Now Im doing that but the result is the same, message saying "Hash is diferent".

Comment: you still compare adresses in the if statement while you have to compare the values in the array like `if(hashResult[i] == hashExpected[i]){` while iterating through the array. Or use a string compare function if the char arrays are `\0` terminated

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I think that now should work, because Im iterating through the arrays and check if each element is icual to the other. But its always showing "hash is the same" even if I change the hashExpected to another.